# set serveroutput ON permanently?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsqldeveloper

I am new in oracle and doing practice for the PL/SQL. I have one question i.e. :
how to set serveroutput ON permanently in oracle. Is their any way that we  use to set it permanently ON?

Comment: You don't set that "*in Oracle*" you set that in your SQL client.

Answer (score 6):

If you are refering to SQL*Plus you should set this in your glogin.sql file.

You can find this file in ORACLE_HOME\sqlplus\admin.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way of setting server output ON permanently.

But if this question is connected to fact that for every new session in SQL developer, 1 needs to execute `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` statement in beginning for seeing *PL/SQL* code result, then solution is `Go to view->DBMS_Output`

Then below you will see dbms output window. There is a plus(+) button there. Click and add schema on which you are working currently. Then *PL/SQL* script output can be seen there.