# PL/SQL command not properly working though successfully completed

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written a simple PL/SQL command of printing hello world to console but it prints nothing and still message is prompted that PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. I am not able to figure it out as to what to do in this case?
Code:

```
BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line ('Hello World..');

END;
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: Besides the fact the correct answer was already given, you can also have a look here, maybe this can prevent you always have to add the "set serverouput on": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185176/set-serveroutput-on-permanently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `set serveroutput on`.

This is what you have:

```
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This is what you should have:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on             --> this
SQL> begin
  2    dbms_output.put_line('Hello world');
  3  end;
  4  /
Hello world                          --> here's the result

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```